# Is there a name for the function $(1 - e^{ct})/(1 - e^{c})$?

Tags: functions, terminology, exponential-function

$$f(t) = \frac{1 - e^{ct}}{1 - e^{c}}$$

This is a function which is somehow a streched exponential which is zero at $t = 0$, and one at $t = 1$, where $c$ determines the curvature (with $c = 0$, it is a line segment).

Is there a common name for this function?

Comment: Maybe not for this function specifically, but perhaps it could be written neatly in terms of hyperbolic functions.

Comment: It's just a regular exponential function, but shifted on the y-axis, inverted, and as you said stretched (if $c<1$. It's expanded if $c>1$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no name, in particular/specifically for your function; as ZettoSuro noted, it's "just a regular exponential function," just shifted down, vertically, and inverted.

It's stretched, depending on the value of $c$: if $0 < c < 1$ it is stretched (less curvature). For $c>1$, it's curvature increases as $c$ increases. But the curve is flipped for negative values of $c$.

Comment: I'm curious about the context behind the question? Where/How did this function "crop up" and engage your attention?

Comment: It is used for envelope segments in the SuperCollider language. There is a number of fixed slopes, like linear, exponential, squared, step-function, etc., and this "parametric exponential" one. These functions are defined so that they begin at zero and end at one over a normalized interval of (0, 1). I have to name this function in a concise way, so `stretched_or_compressed_inverted_exp` is not good. I will probably just go for `curvilinear` or `parametric` then.

Comment: That will work (capture all possible "shapes" the curve can take). Perhaps "parametric exponential" is as good as it will get. Nice function, since you can consider the "line" at c = 0 to be a "degenerate" exponential. :-) Sorry I couldn't be of greater help!

Comment: @amWhy: That seems as good as anything! +1